# ZedGraph - Part of line graph not showing

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph to plot a very large data set (ranges from 500,000 data points to as much as 30 million data points).  The chart style is a line graph.  In all, there are 3 separate plots of the data set after the data set has been passed through different filters.  Essentially, this means the 3 plots will be a little different from each other.

My problem is this:  two of the plots render from the left edge of the chart to the right edge of the chart perfectly fine, but the third plot (the green line in the picture below) starts on the left edge of the chart and then stops half-way across.  As I zoom out, the third plot (green one) will get bigger as more points are plotted.

Can anyone provide details as to why this might happen, and how I can get the third plot to draw across the entire chart?

[image: Three plots]

(**Note, in the picture the second plot-- the red line-- is drawn over the first plot since the results for these data sets are nearly the same.**)

Edit: I'm still having trouble with this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: update to the latest ZedGraph.  I had been using version 5.0.2.  Updating to 5.1.5 solved the problem.